# Save lattice plot with no surrounding white area in R

Tags: r, pdf, plot, lattice, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to save a lattice plot in R, without any white space.
I'm adjusting the aspect ratio of the plot like this

```
y = rnorm(15)
x = 1:15 
my_plot = barchart( y~x, horiz=F, aspect=0.4)
```

What I'd like is to get the dimensions of the output pdf such that the plot fills the pdf file without any white area surrounding the plot.

Here's what I've tried:

```
# Get aspect ratio
asp = my_plot$aspect.ratio

# Adjust height/width to aspect ratio
pdf('~/Desktop/test.pdf', width=8, height=8 * asp)
plot(my_plot)
dev.off()
```

However, I'm still getting white areas around the plot:
[image]

Any idea how I can get the plot to fill the output pdf?

Thanks

Comment: I find easier to use system tool such as `pdfcrop`.

Comment: @Pascal thanks, seems like a really useful tool. However, I'd prefer a workaround in R for this particular case.

Comment: I never found a workaround in R. If someone has, I would be interested.

Comment: Try tweaking the padding... `my_plot = barchart( y~x, horiz=F, aspect=0.4,
                    par.settings=list(layout.heights=list(top.padding=-5,
                                                          bottom.padding=-5,
                                                          left.padding=-5,
                                                          right.padding=-5)))`

Comment: Great stuff, please feel free to write it up as an asnwer, as you did most of the hard work setting asp. (btw you can see things that can be tweaked with `trellis.par.get()`)

Comment: Ahh. it screws up if you add a title to the plot for example.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed your comment - yes the title messes it up, thats annoying. However, with some extra work, you can manually add one using grid.text and viewports:  `grid.newpage(); pushViewport(viewport(y=1, height=0.15, just="top")); grid.text("My Title", gp=gpar(col="red", cex=1.5)); upViewport(); pushViewport(viewport(y=0, height=0.85, just="bottom")); print(my_plot, newpage=FALSE); upViewport() `
(still messes it up but perhaps less?)

Comment: or... `gridExtra::grid.arrange(my_plot, top="My Title")`